# Oracle SQL: Find each position of specific character in multi-row column without duplicates

Tags: sql, string, oracle, duplicates

I am trying to find the position of a given character (`¬`) in a column of strings. This method works perfectly well for a single row and correctly returns a row per match with the position in the string. However when I add more rows in it causes duplicates. The more I add the higher the number of duplicates it generates.

I've worked out that, if N is the number of input rows, it causes the first match to show 1 times, the second to show N, the third onwards to show N^2 times but cannot work out why.

For small datasets I am okay using a distinct but this quickly gets too slow to run as I add more rows and more matches.

How would I fix this code to only return a single row per position per original row?

```
WITH TEST_TABLE AS (
SELECT 'test 1 ¬ test  ¬2' AS NOTE FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL SELECT 'test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'test 5 ¬ tester ¬ 6' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'test 7 ¬ tester ¬ 8' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
)

SELECT  
    note, INSTR(NOTE,'¬', 1, LEVEL) POS, REGEXP_COUNT(NOTE, '¬')
    FROM test_table
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(NOTE, '¬')
    order by 1, 2
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option:

```
SQL> WITH TEST_TABLE AS (
  2  SELECT 'test 1 ¬ test  ¬2' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
  3  UNION ALL SELECT 'test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
  4  UNION ALL SELECT 'test 5 ¬ tester ¬ 6' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
  5  UNION ALL SELECT 'test 7 ¬ tester ¬ 8' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
  6  )
  7  SELECT
  8    note,
  9    INSTR(NOTE,'¬', 1, column_value) POS, REGEXP_COUNT(NOTE, '¬')
 10  FROM test_table,
 11       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(NOTE, '¬')
 13                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14  order by 1, 2;

NOTE                                            POS REGEXP_COUNT(NOTE,'¬')
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------------------
test 1 ¬ test  ¬2                                 8                      2
test 1 ¬ test  ¬2                                16                      2
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay              8                      4
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay             17                      4
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay             31                      4
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay             34                      4
test 5 ¬ tester ¬ 6                               8                      2
test 5 ¬ tester ¬ 6                              17                      2
test 7 ¬ tester ¬ 8                               8                      2
test 7 ¬ tester ¬ 8                              17                      2

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CROSS APPLY query:

```
WITH TEST_TABLE AS (
SELECT 'test 1 ¬ test  ¬2' AS NOTE FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL SELECT 'test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'test 5 ¬ tester ¬ 6' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'test 7 ¬ tester ¬ 8' AS NOTE FROM DUAL
)

SELECT  x.*
FROM TEST_TABLE t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT t.note, INSTR(t.NOTE,'¬', 1, LEVEL) POS, REGEXP_COUNT(t.NOTE, '¬')
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t.NOTE, '¬')
) x
    order by 1, 2
    ;
```

---

```
NOTE                                            POS REGEXP_COUNT(NOTE,'¬')
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------------------
test 1 ¬ test  ¬2                                 8                      2
test 1 ¬ test  ¬2                                16                      2
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay              8                      4
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay             17                      4
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay             31                      4
test 3 ¬ tester ¬ 4 test yayay¬ay¬ay             34                      4
test 5 ¬ tester ¬ 6                               8                      2
test 5 ¬ tester ¬ 6                              17                      2
test 7 ¬ tester ¬ 8                               8                      2
test 7 ¬ tester ¬ 8                              17                      2

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the database is 11g so can't run cross apply, but I assume it would work!